# Replace word in text file comma separated with word in a specific column with Python

Tags: python, text, replace

Sorry but I am just stating Python and need some lights

I have a list like below:

```
$ cat server.txt
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
server1, windows, 120, running , 1
server2, linux, 250, offline , 1
server3, centos, 60, maintenance, 0
server4, windows, 123, running, 1
server5, linux, 145, offline, 0
```

I need to replace the second column with other values like:

All the 1 in the column5 are replace by the word **noissue** an the 0 with the word **issue**
but only the in column5 as I don't want to have the column3 impacted by the change

Many thanks

Comment: Read each line. Split each line by comma. Change the last element (the one you want to modify). Write in a new file each line. Rename the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you are sure that the column to replace only contains 0 and 1.

```
firstline = True
with open("server.txt") as f:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fw:
        for line in f.readlines(): # For each line in server.txt

            if firstline: # Do not process the header line
                firstline = False
                continue

            if line[-2] == "1": # -2 because -1 is the line return character
                line = line[:-2] + "noissue\n"
            else:
                line = line[:-2] + "issue\n"
            fw.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks julienc, your code is working as expected but I have another question :), how can we update it to be able to change the value if they were in the column2 and knowing that the server name may be of different length?

Comment: Well, in that case, you should look at the two other answers. Mine would need too many changes to work with these new conditions...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
mapping = {'0':'issue', '1':'noissue'}
for line in sys.stdin:
  fields = line.split(',')
  if fields[4].strip() in mapping:
    fields[4] = mapping[fields[4].strip()]
  print ','.join(fields)
```

This will work on the *standard input* and write to *stdout*, so you'll have to call your program like

```
$ python program.py < server.txt > output.txt
```

if there's neither a "0" nor a "1" in the column, the value will not be changed. You can adapt the `mapping`, if you want to change other values too.

Note that this program doesn't handle the first line separately (see julinenc's posting to see how this could be done). As you have no '0' or '1' in your first line it will work with the example you've posted.

Also note the use of the `strip()` method, this gets rid of possible additional spaces around your "0" and "1"

Comment: Nice, but you can replace your if loop with `fields[4] = mapping.get(fields[4].strip(), fields[4])`, `get()` takes an optional second argument which is the value to return if the key doesn't exist. It defaults to `None`, but here I am replacing it with the value of the `fields[4]`. In effect, "if a replacement exists, get it, otherwise return the looked up value".

Comment: Thanks MartinStettner for the code. This is working but the output adding blank line between the line. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Thanks Burhan Khalid, I may have some lines with only 2 columns the code you provided give an error if the value doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `csv` module for this:

```
import csv

with open('server.txt', 'r') as infile, open('server_modified.txt','w') as outfile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')  # ',' is the default, but this shows
                                               # you how to change it in the future
   writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerow(next(reader)) # This will write the first row (your header)
                                 # directly to the output file

   for row in reader:
      if row[-1] == '1':
         row[-1] = 'noissue'

      if row[-1] == '0':
         row[-1] = 'issue'

      writer.writerow(row)
```